# How to install Microsoft Office 2010 on Debian Jessie?

Tags: microsoft-word, debian-jessie

I need to use Microsoft Office 2010 with Debian Jessie. I know that there is Libre Office alternative but it is not enough for me. 
How I can do it without pain of daily usage?

Comment: How to install newest wine for Debian Jessie http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

You can find many tutorial on the web about installing Office 2k10 on ubuntu, the same procedure might work since Ubuntu is based on Debian, here is a tutrial here http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

[Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover) is a paid product that is specifically designed to enable you to run Microsoft Office on Linux (it used to be called Crossover Office).

It is made by the company (CodeWeavers) who do the vast majority of the development on Wine, so by purchasing the product you are supporting Wine development too.